# total and group query

Tags: mysql

[My database rows/columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1J8h.jpg)

Good day!
I have my database, and it was setup like this.

I want to total the amount for Roderick from the period of 12/13/2016 until 12/16/2016 from level 1 up to level 4 using their assigned ID.

Example;

Roderick ID is 001 and his income from 12/13/2016 between 12/16/2016 is 270.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack overflow please read this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please show us what you have done by providing some code so we can help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT s.username,SUM(s.amount) as amount
FROM(SELECT level1 as username,amount1 as amount
     FROM YourTable 
     WHERE date between '12/13/2016' and '12/16/2016'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT level2 as username,amount2 as amount
     FROM YourTable 
     WHERE date between '12/13/2016' and '12/16/2016'
     UNION ALL
     .... ) s
GROUP BY s.username
```

Comment: Thanks sagi for your quick answer. I maybe need to refine it for me to get exactly the procedure. Here is the actual setup on my db.
http://i.imgur.com/ufSlT7a.jpg